# What is the purpose of using np.random.random(4) for plotting pie charts using matplotlib?

Tags: numpy, pie-chart, numpy-random

I am relatively new to matplotlib.

```
 ax.pie(np.random.random(4), explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors,
   autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90,
   radius=0.25, center=(0, 0), frame=True)
ax.pie(np.random.random(4), explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors,
   autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90,
   radius=0.25, center=(1, 1), frame=True)
ax.pie(np.random.random(4), explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors,
   autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90,
   radius=0.25, center=(0, 1), frame=True)
ax.pie(np.random.random(4), explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors,
   autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90,
   radius=0.25, center=(1, 0), frame=True)

# Set aspect ratio to be equal so that pie is drawn as a circle.
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

http://%3Chttp://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_demo_features.html%3E

Answer (score 0):

It's common practice to generate random "fake" input data as a convenient way to demonstrate what a function does. In this case [`np.random.random`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.random.html) is simply being used to generate four random numbers between 0 and 1 to determine the sizes of each "wedge" in the pie chart. Normally you would pass in the "real" (non-random) values you want to plot in the form of a numpy array or list.